# How to cycle through a list and sort by date

Tags: vb.net, sorting

My ultimate goal is to have two radio buttons. One for Alphabetical and one for Chronological. The alphabetical is easy, because i just set the Sort property to true. But I am confused on how to sort by date, if at all possible.

The data in the listbox is something to the effect of:

```
This is my data name 08/24/2011 1:18:02 PM
This is another name 12/05/2011 7:33:13 AM
```

Comment: The right way to do that would be to use a list as the datasource for the listbox.  If the list contained objects you could sort it by whichever property you desired

Comment: I am still new to VB.NET. The great thing here, I believe, is that the data coming in to the listbox is coming from a sql query. So it would seem setting a datasource directly from the returned results is already going to be a breeze. I don't know how to do this so I can do more research online with your advice. Thank you!

Comment: in *that* case. a DataGridView might be a better choice than the ListBox and use a/the datatable as the source

Comment: I don't know if I agree with that because I am giving the user an option to delete lines of data they do not need. I don't know if removing an entire row in a DGV is as easy as it is with a listbox. Also, the user is going to push a button that will cycle through each list item and print a document using an image path.

Comment: With a datasource you do not remove (or add) to the control, you modify the source (List<T>, DataTable etc), so yes, it is just as easy.